# MongoDB slower queries on find( ) if indexes are duplicate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

Duplicate entries in collection indexes are necessary to my database because of nature of multi-tenancy use.

l have a collection “products” as:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId,
  businessID: String (indexed),
  productCode: String (indexed),
  productName: String,
  keyN: valN,
  .....
}
```

so as we can see, this collection consists of products of all the businesses, each having unique businessID and all their products entered in this collection

the businessID is indexed without any unique flag, which means false by default

the issue i’m stuck is on the performance while doing find( ) queries. since, there are only 2,544,436 documents in this collection (as of now) with 710 unique businessID.

```
db.products.countDocuments()
// 2544436

db.products.distinct("businessID").length
// 710

db.products.getIndexes()
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { businessID: 1 },
    name: 'businessID_1',
    background: true
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { productCode: 1 },
    name: 'productCode_1',
    background: true
  }
]
```

but the query
`db.products.find({businessID: “617e557b88c7914a420e3211”})` takes about 50ms+ which is quite fast, but I’m not sure how it will scale if it’ll get let’s say a larger set of docs later on with thousands of distinct businessID.

are there any options of setting flags like { commonIndex: true } or something like that so that the queries are faster, since the indexes are already set and the common indexes of _id can be counted mapping the businessID, shouldn’t it be faster to get exact those documents with those key indexes?

Comment: did you have tried to use the `explain` option?

Comment: @DavidA.
yes, while looking at the executionstats data, the response time are fine... both 0ms for fetch and ixscan... but in mongoose, it takes around 50ms without any other extra operation queries attached

Answer (score 0):

As your design of the collection is multi-tenancy, which will require businessID as a filter for every query, why don’t you create a compound index to cater to the queries?  You can refer to the following document: [Compound Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-compound/)

Comment: i'm familiar with compound indexes and have used this for other use cases but this case is different, i need data of a particular businessID among all other businessID. the find query returns about 1000 documents for a single businessID. the thing i'm concerned is that the query is quite slower.
if 1000 documents over ~50ms - 100ms acceptable then it isn't the issue. just that i'm not sure about how it'll scale further.